# Return array from node.js readline module on close event

Tags: node.js, csv, stream, readline, fs

I'm calling a function on the server side that opens a csv file and searches for a string in each line. On the close event, the function should return an array that contains the first 5 string matches from the csv file (in the first column). However, it seems the array is unaccessible outside the function (possibly due to asynchronous behaviour):

**index.js**

```
function calling_function()
{
    var a_string = "foo";
    var array = database_search(a_string);
    console.log(array); 
}

function database_search(a_string)
{
    var result = ["", "", "", "", ""];

    var csv_file = readline.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/Static/a_file.csv')
    });

    var cntr = 0;

    csv_file.on('line', function (line) {
        if(line.indexOf(a_string) > -1)
        {
            if(cntr < 5)
            {
                result[cntr] = line.split(",")[0];
            }
            else
            {
                csv_file.close();
            }
            cntr++;
        }
    });

    csv_file.on('close', function() {
        return result; // not returning result array
    });
}
```

What would be the correct way to access an array outside the readline on close event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the "csv_file.on" event you are in the scope of a callback function.
In order to get the array you can do the following:

```
function calling_function()
{
    var a_string = "foo";
    var array = []
    database_search(a_string ,arr => {
        array = arr 
        console.log(array);
    });
}

function database_search(a_string ,callback)
{
    var result = ["", "", "", "", ""];

    var csv_file = readline.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/Static/a_file.csv')
    });

    var cntr = 0;

    csv_file.on('line', function (line) {
        if(line.indexOf(a_string) > -1)
        {
            if(cntr < 5)
            {
                result[cntr] = line.split(",")[0];
            }
            else
            {
                csv_file.close();
            }
            cntr++;
        }
    });

    // notice i added the 'result' in the callback function parameter
    csv_file.on('close', function(result) {
        callback(result)
    });
}
```

Comment: It still seems to be returning undefined

Comment: try log the result
        csv_file.on('close', function(result) {
       console.log(result)
    callback(result)
});

see if its returns the result as you expected.

Comment: Ok, got it to work with a slight adjustment to your answer :) just had to get rid of passing "result" as a parameter in the readline close anonymous callback function (since it creates a new variable "result" instead of using the original "result" containing an array): csv_file.on('close', function() {callback(result) });