# Javascript - how to access the result within readfile close event and return it to initial function

Tags: javascript, arrays, lookup, readline

I am using readline to read a text file line-by-line and process it with some filtering. The text file contains lots of abbreviations and the corresponding whole word or sentence. For example "BTW" stands for "by the way". Within readlines line-by-line section I am doing some filtering and push the desired lines into an array.

The final array looks like that, which I can access successful on the 'close' event and output the data as desired.

var arr = [ { wholeword: 'by the way', abbr: 'btw' },{ wholeword: 'see ya', abr: 'cya' },{ wholeword: 'be right back', abbr: 'brb' } ]

I am struggling to return the result to the invoking position. I am not sure if and how this is possible because readline uses this extra event called 'close'. Does it need to work with callback somehow? Never worked with them before and it would need me to dig into it. I just need some hints where to look at, please shed some light into it.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

function lookup(abbreviation) {
  var arr = [];
  const readFile = readline.createInterface({
   input: fs.createReadStream('abbreviations.txt'),
   crlfDelay: Infinity
  });

  readFile.on('line', line => {

    if ( line.match( /#/ ) ) {
    fields      = line.split( ':' ).slice();
      arr.push({
        foo: fields[0].trim(),
        bar: fields[1].trim(),
        abbr: fields[2].trim(),
        wholeword: fields[3].trim(),
      });
     }
  });

  readFile.on('close', function()  {
    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++){
      if (arr[i].abbr == abbreviation){
       let needthis = arr[i].wholeword;
       console.log(arr[i].abbr + " --> " + needthis);
       return needthis;
      }
    }
});
}
```

lookup(btw);

should return "**by the way**" but actually it returns just **undefined**. However the console.log output inside my 'close' section of readline is successful. It just doesn't return the result to the invoking call. I did find this thread here ([Return array from node.js readline module on close event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52914673/return-array-from-node-js-readline-module-on-close-event)) but I wasn't able to reflect it to my code with success. Either I got "callback is not a function" or no value was reported back as expected. Obviously I did something wrong when trying to implement the suggestions from that post.

## 1st question is:

**How do I return the needthis/result correctly?**

Additionally I'd like to learn and understand what the best practice for a good performant lookup on this example is. Actually I am opening+reading+processing the text file on each lookup. I guess this is not good and it would make more sense to have the text file read only once in the beginning and write the necessary wanted lines into the array. Each lookup should then use this array as lookup table to find the corresponding line and output the abbreviated word.

## 2nd question is:

**What would be the most performant approach for a lookup?**

Comment: anyone? I have no clue how to solve this and thus any assistance is appreciated. The most important question is (1), how can I access the result for the desired lookup?

Comment: please any hint where to look at. How can one use the result from the close statement in other parts of the javascript code outside the readline scope?

Answer (score 0):

I have found and solved my isse by myself and here is the answer:

it was really simple and I overlooked it in the beginning. I need to hoist the variable declaration to the top, outside the lookup function. It should look like that:

```
  var arr = [];

function lookup(abbreviation) {

  const readFile = readline.createInterface({
   input: fs.createReadStream('abbreviations.txt'),
   crlfDelay: Infinity
  });
[...]
```

Additionally to answer my question 2)

I removed the block from the readline/close scope and made a separate lookup function. The shown function here was renamed and used as a single call function which is processing the abbreviation file once in the beginning when the application starts. The function populates and fills the array "arr". With my extra lookup function I can access this array "arr" and as soon as the searching pattern is matched in the for-loop I break the loop and return the lookup value.

Issue solved.